# how should I use assert an bool to verify if a function is sorting my array corectly

Tags: c++

I used this to verify if a number is prime or not and I do not know how should I use this for an array.  Should I use a for loop to verify with an already aranged one?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
using namespace std;
bool e_prim(int nr) {
    if(nr < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if(nr == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if(nr % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int d = 3;
    while(d * d <= nr) {
        if(nr % d == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        d += 2;
    }
    return true;
}


void test_nr_prim() {
    assert(e_prim(-17) == false);
    assert(e_prim(0) == false);
    assert(e_prim(1) == false);
    assert(e_prim(2) == true);
    assert(e_prim(6) == false);
    assert(e_prim(17) == true);
    assert(e_prim(15) == false);
    assert(e_prim(25) == false);
}
```

Comment: The title looks completely unrelated to the question body.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: I mean how should i adapt this aproach for an array, ye it s not the best title but I am tired af

Comment: iterate over array and assert that along 2 neighboring numbers, left one is smaller than one on a right. `assert(arr[i] <= arr[i+1])` (assuming sorting is ascending)

Comment: @phuclv thx for the advise, I am new here and still learning

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard library function templates [`all_of` and `none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
void test_nr_prim() {
    int const primes[] { 2, 17, 23, };
    int const non_primes[] { -17, 0, 1, 6, 15, 25, };
    assert(std::all_of(std::begin(primes), std::end(primes), e_prim));
    assert(std::none_of(std::begin(non_primes), std::end(non_primes), e_prim));
}
```

Comment: Nice - and in C++20, the `assert`s could be made into `static_assert`s. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/TeTvKv4sf)

Comment: @TedLyngmo good point. Then, you don't even need to invoke the function since `static_cast` works regardless.